# How to put a gamma into my latex document

Tags: unicode

I have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

I typed

```
something something γ something
```

I am getting the error "Package inputenc Error: Unicode character γ (U+03B3)" and it won't render in the output

How can I make that and other modern greek render?

I don't want to use `[english, greek]{babel}` and select language just for single words at a time

`$\gamma$` isn't a solution because math-mode gamma is italicised, and I want the gamma I type using my keyboard γγγγ to render as exactly that (in the typeface that the document is in or whichever most similar typeface supports it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, load `fontspec` and select fonts that contain Greek, such as New Computer Modern or Computer Modern Unicode.  Either `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}` or `\usepackage{libertinus}` should do it.

In PDFLaTeX, you need to load the LGR encoding and the `textgreek` package for this to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}
something something γ something
\end{document}
```

This gives you a Greek letter as it would appear in an actual Greek word, which might look different from a math symbol.

An alternative way to get the math symbol is to declare the letter active with `newunicodechar`:

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{γ}{\ensuremath{\gamma}}
```

You could also use  (U+1D6FE) for the mathematical symbol, declaring it the same way.  This will not conflict with actual Greek text, should you need it.

Comment: adding `\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}` after `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` worked

Comment: @theonlygusti On some particularly old installations, you might need to put `fontenc` before `inputenc`. Since 2018, you haven’t needed `inputenc`; UTF-8 is the default. But that works.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B3}{$\gamma$}
\begin{document}
something something γ something $\gamma$
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this is italicised

Comment: was that mentioned in the question

Comment: okay thanks I'll specify